# How do you deploy the "Building REST Services with Spring" tutorial?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

As someone who is new to Java and Spring, I've been working through their REST API tutorials. A general workflow is introduced where you embed Jetty/Tomcat and then run an executable Jar file. This workflow appears to change when the [Building REST Services with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) tutorial is introduced. Their [bookmarks demo project](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks) uses a multi-module maven configuration. There doesn't appear to be a main manifest attribute defined anywhere.

The Maven configuration currently generates a separate jar for each module.

The ideal goal would be to take the bookmarks demo project, add [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to it, and loop in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). The realistic goal is to get the project running using Jetty or Tomcat.

Do you know how I could deploy the [Spring Bookmarks Demo](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks) using Jetty or Tomcat? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guide can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) but in short these are the things you will have to do:

1. The class annotated as `@SpringBootApplication` (where the main method is) must extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and Override the configure method (basic sample below)
2. Modify your build system to generate a WAR file
3. Mark Tomcat/Jetty as provided
4. Deploy your WAR file to your container (there are plenty of ways to do this but they are independent of your implementation)

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Application.class);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```

---

There is a SpringBoot Getting Started Guide for [Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) I recommend you go through it before changing anything as SpringBoot has extensive Docker support and you might not need to change you application to a WAR file.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, when I try to add this method to any of the existing application classes then Eclipse raises "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project". Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't add it to just any class you have to add it to the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. In the Spring Getting Started Examples this is more often then not called Application.java

Answer (score 1):

If the project is a maven project, then use the package goal to build your deployment unit using 'mvn package' and deploy the resulting .war (assuming that is how you've configured it).

If the example is already configured to run with an embedded Jetty, then you don't need to build a deployable unit and deploy it anywhere else, you just run it - that's the point of an embedded container; it's already configured to include it's own runtime, you just run it.